# Facebook JavaScript SDK: FB.getLoginStatus and FB.Login doesn't work on Chrome

Tags: javascript, facebook, google-chrome, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

FB.getLoginStatus and FB.Login doesn't work on Chrome.
version 44.0.2403.125 (64-bit)

why?

but on Safari and fireFox , It work.

How would it work on Chrome?

code:

```
//facebook
//the basic version of the SDK
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : CLIENT_ID,//facebook appID
    cookie     : true,
    xfbml      : true,
    version    : 'v2.3'
  });

  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response){
    console.log(response);
  });
};
// Load the SDK asynchronously
(function(d, s, id){
   var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
   if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
   js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
   js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
   fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
 }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

on click FBLoginButton :

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  if (response.status === 'connected') {
    console.log('Logged in.');
    console.log(response);
  }
  else {
    FB.login(function(response) {
      if (response.authResponse) {
        console.log(response);
      } else {
        console.log('FB login error!');
      }
    }, {scope: permissions});
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I settled it.

"AdBlock" on Chrome disturbed Facebook javaScript SDK.

This is why Facebook javaScript SDk doesn't work on Chrome.